# Can open and closed manifolds be combined in non-trivial ways?

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

For example an infinite line and a circle. You can form a cross product which is an infinite tube.

What about a sphere and a plane? Can they be combined to form a manifold which is not a simple cross product of the two? What about higher dimensions such as $\mathbb{R}^4$ with $S_4$. Can they be combined so that the 8 dimensional manifold is not just the product of the two? Are there some examples.

I am thinking of the way, in group theory, SU(2) and SU(3) can be embedded in SU(5) which contains the cross product SU(2)xSU(3) but is not a simple cross product itself.

I wondered if open and closed spaces can be combined in non-trivial ways too?

(What got me thinking is that if the Universe is infinite and 4 dimensional and has some compact dimensions on a sphere, say, is the manifold always just the cross product of the open and closed spaces or can it be part of something more interesting?)

Comment: Well, there are always fiber bundles.

Comment: My understanding of fibre bundles is that they are not much more interesting than cross products? Or are they more interesting in higher dimensions? How many types of fibre bundles exist for example for $\mathbb{R}^4\times S_4$ ?

Comment: Yes. A [fiber bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_bundle) $F\to E\to B$ is basically a space $E$ which is a bunch of copies of $E$ parametrized by $B$. They can be much less trivial than trivial bundles (*Cartesian* products). There is an entire branch of mathematics devoted to studying just *vector* bundles. Re: your edit, do you mean how many isomorphism classes of bundles $\Bbb R^4\to E\to S^4$ there are?

Comment: They are locally homeomorphic to the product but globally they may not resemble the product of the two spaces at all.

Comment: Are there any interesting examples which one could visualise? Or are they not really visualisable? I'm imagining say a sphere at each point in space rotated in various ways, the direction perhaps given by a tensor field? Am I close?

Comment: In dimension two, both a cylinder and a Mobius band are bundles $[0,1]\to E\to S^1$. The real line $\Bbb R$ is a nontrivial bundle $\Bbb Z\to\Bbb R\to S^1$. For any finite set $X$, there is a bundle $X\to S^1\to S^1$. For any $n$ there is a bundle $\Bbb Z_2\to S^{n-1}\to \mathbb{RP}^{n-1}$. The $3$-sphere $S^3$, which may be thought of as $\Bbb R^3\cup\{\infty\}$, can be decomposed into circles arranged in the pattern of a $2$-sphere: this is the so-called Hopf fibration $S^1\to S^3\to S^2$ (google this to get nice pictures).

Comment: Yeah I get the mobius strip but that's too simple to be interesting. From that I am getting that higher dimensional versions would be like cross products but with various twists in them. But I can't really visualise that too well. Also,  am more interested in fibre bundles on open spaces. Maybe they have an infinite number of twists! (I like the Hopf vibration example.)

Comment: (continued) For Lie subgroups $H\le G$, there is a fiber bundle $H\to G\to G/H$. This covers a huge class of examples, and is a spiritual generalization of the orbit-stabilizer theorem. The tangent bundle of a sphere $\Bbb R^{n-1}\to TS^{n-1}\to S^{n-1}$ is trivial (i.e. $TS^{n-1}\simeq \Bbb R^{n-1}\times S^{n-1}$) precisely when $n=0,1,3,7$, which correspond to the four real normed division algebras $\mathbb{R,C,H,O}$ (reals, complex numbers, quaternions, octonions). (BTW, $\Bbb Z\to \Bbb R\to S^1$ is already an example with an infinite number of twists.)

Comment: OK. I think my brain melted. I'm going to have to read up more about this!

Comment: If I could offer a modest "ahem" here.  Fiber bundles are extremely interesting, at least as far as Steenrod, Milnor, Bott, Atiyah, Hirzebruch, and countless others were concerned.  So, yes, they're worth studying, and plenty of modern cosmologists utilize them heavily in their work on gauge theory and the topological structure of the universe.  Oh, and one last thing, don't be so quick to dismiss the Mobius band.  It happens to be the canonical line bundle over $\mathbb{R}P^1$ and it plays an important role in the theory of characteristic classes.